# Pinging IP throws Request timed out but successful response is received on pinging the URL. Which n/w component may be responding to the ping on URL

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, ping

I'm running a performance test on an application hosted on AWS. To check the network latency I tried pinging the URL which worked. But if I try to ping the IP address of the VM on which the application is hosted (it's using a static IP for testing purpose) Request timed out exception is thrown. The resolved address while pinging the URL is also different from the application host IP.

I'm curious which component on the network may be replying to the ping while hitting the URL - the dns, load balancer of the cloud or anything else?

Comment: There is no such thing as "pinging the URL". What did you actually do?

Comment: Hi Abhijit, if the response below answered your question please upvote and accept it. That's the ServerFault's way to say thank you for the time and effort someone took to help you. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've got a *Load Balancer* (as you briefly mention) the host name in the URL will most likely resolve to the Load Balancer IP.

Your VM (or *EC2 Instance* in AWS speak) is "hidden" behind the load balancer and quite likely won't be accessible from outside. Either because it doesn't have a **Public IP** at all (the LB can talk to it over private IP), and/or the **Security Group** doesn't permit access from the internet and only permits access from the Load Balancer. That would be a common AWS deployment pattern.

Anyway for **Performance testing** you should only care about HTTP/HTTPS throughput, latency, page load times, serving concurrent requests, etc. Pinging either the LB or the EC2 is quite pointless and won't tell you much about the **actual performance** of your website.

In other words - use your performance testing tool, point it to the Load Balancer URL and measure that performance as that's what ultimately affects your users.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thanks for your input. On a high level it explained the problem. I discovered there was a reverse-proxy in place. The reply to my ping request was being delivered by the proxy. I was not trying to analyze performance of the application through this activity. The aim was to figure out the network latency.